# How to let GKE pods connect to local device

Tags: gke-networking, google-cloud-vpn

I am new to K8s and GKE. I have a VPC subnet 10.3.0.0/16, and I have VPN tunnel connect to local gateway, so if I create a Compute Engine on this VPC subnet, I can successfully ping to a local IP like 192.168.15.230.
But when I create a GKE cluster on this VPC subnet, I found that pods on GKE cluster hosted on another IPv4 address range 10.65.0.0/17.
If I want to let Pod connect to local IP 192.168.15.230, what should I do?

What I have tried:

- When I was creating a GKE cluster on VPC subnet 10.3.0.0/16, I found that setting Cluster default pod address range on 10.3.0.0/16 is not allowed. What should I do to set it to be on VPC subnet 10.3.0.0/16? Or is this concept correct?
- I tried create a Compute Engine instance on VPC subnet 10.3.0.0/16 and start a docker container in it. Then I go a 172.18.*.* IP and I can connect to local IP 192.168.15.230 in this container. But why can't I connect to local IP in a GKE pod?

Comment: your nodes are getting created in another VPC or subnet ? as range is changing so that's the reason, POD schedules on nodes and If nodes on diff VPC it might wont be having the VPN peering what i guess.

Comment: Hi @HarshManvar, I think you are right. I found a solution here :https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent
I need to configure nonMasqueradeCIDRs for 10.3.0.0/16, so that the pods can connect to on-primise device.